# element not visible Selenium capybara

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

[image]I am getting below error while executing below capybara command,
The interesting thing is the same XPath is not giving any error in I am expecting that XPath to be present.
But when I am trying to perform click on that XPath, it's throwing below error.

--------------code----------------

Then(/^I click on "([^"]*)" on left tree child of "([^"]*)"$/) do |child, parent|

within(:xpath, ".//div/span[@class='folder-nav-tree-fileroom' and text()='DND-IndexTwistyExpClps']/../../../../..", wait:5) do

```
find(:xpath, ".//span[contains(text(),  '1 IndexTwistyLevel1')]/../../../span[@class='ui-tree-toggler  fa fa-fw fa-caret-right']",  wait:5).click
```

end

end

```
Error : Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible xpath "//div[.//span[contains(text(),  '1 IndexTwistyLevel1')]]/span[@class='ui-tree-toggler  fa fa-fw fa-caret-right']"
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a number of issues, which indicate it can't actually be working like you claim.  If you fix the code and provide the HTML fragment it should be matching against we can narrow done to the issue, but for now the errors are:

Firstly, you have mismatched/non-escaped
 's and )s in your XPath expressions (can't have `inside a string surrounded by`s so it's obvious you haven't copy/pasted your actual code)

Secondly, `::after` is not valid XPath - `::after` pseudo elements are purely CSS and can't be accessed from XPath, so including that in your selector isn't going to give the expected results.  This should result in an invalid selector error being raised by Chrome.

Thirdly, by not starting your selectors with `.` you're completely defeating the `within` scoping block - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap

Finally, using `visible: false` on an element you want to click makes no sense, since you can't click on an element that isn't displayed on the page.

Unfortunately its tough to tell which of these may be causing your actual issue (if any) since the code you have provided isn't valid.

Comment: Hey Thomas Walpole , Thanks for the quick response : below is the update code .within(:xpath, "//div/span[@class='folder-nav-tree-fileroom' and text()='TEXT']/../../../../..") do
  if page.all(:xpath, "//div[.//span[contains(text(),  ' 1 IndexTwistyLevel1 ')]]/span[@class='ui-tree-toggler  fa fa-fw fa-caret-right']").count == 1
    puts "i got the match"
  end
  find(:xpath, "//div[.//span[contains(text(),  ' 1 IndexTwistyLevel1 ')]]/span[@class='ui-tree-toggler  fa fa-fw fa-caret-right']").click
end

Comment: @asingh Please just edit/fix your question so the code is actually readable - and with the code you've put in your comment there is still no point in having a `within` since you completely defeat it with your xpath expressions - the third point in my answer

Comment: Hey Thomas, as per point 3, i have updated the code, ran it got error element not visible, I have updated the question and the code. Plz have a look, and again thank you so much for your time

Comment: @asingh From the code in the question - you haven't fixed point 3 - since the xpath expression inside the within block (the one that you want scoped still doesn't start with a `.`) - and the error shown in your question is "unable to find" not "element not visible"

Comment: @asingh Additionally - what are the dimension of the actual span element - in your image you show the dimensions of the ::after pseudo element, but not those of the actual span element (which is what you can find and click on)

Comment: Hey Thomas, ::after some angular js call is happening, and the xpath which i am using to click on the circle which i have highlighted in the image, is gettign pointed out correctly when i am verifying that element with that xpath from console., what exactly you mean when you say dimensions of actual span element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154610/discussion-between-asingh-and-thomas-walpole).

Comment: @twalpole, i have again updated the xpath in within block and m still hitting same error, element not found with visible xpath, but when i am verifying that xpath from console it rightly matched the element

Comment: @asignh the image you have posted shows the `::after` pseudo element as having a size of 13x13 pixels -- if instead you highlight the actual `span` element - what size does that show?  Also, what command exactly are you running from the console which you think matches the element? Additionally the string shown in the error you have pasted doesn't match the code (the spacing in the @class part of the XPath query is different) -- can you just edit the question so it has all matching info - ie the code you're actually running and the actual error from that code.

Answer (score 0):

```
within(:xpath, config['documents_obj']['FRChildTreeXpath'].sub('TEXT', parent), wait:5) do
elem = find(:xpath, config['documents_obj']['childTwistyXpath'].sub('TEXT', child), visible:false,  wait:5).native
page.driver.browser.action.click(elem).perform
```

To avoid the error which iwas gettign what i simply did, is I used capybara action builder,
Take the native element then perform the action.

It worked perfectly in my case.

Reference : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html